# Button Rotation 3D Objects ARKit 2

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, scenekit, arkit

I have 3D objects that are triggered by image detection. I added buttons so the user can view the object in different views such as left, right, top, bottom, etc. My code has a flaw as the rotation point is set from the last touch. For example, if you press right, it goes .pi/2 then when you press left it goes -.pi/2, resetting it back to the front view instead of the left view. How am I able to set an original front origin so the rotate "resets" after every press and it goes to the according view? Thanks.

```
@IBAction func leftSideRotate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: -.pi/2, z: 0, duration: 0.5)
    sender.isEnabled = false
    toggleButton = sender
    activeNode?.runAction(rotate,completionHandler: enableButtonn)
}
func enableButtonn (){
    toggleButton?.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func upSole(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: -.pi/2, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 0.5)
    sender.isEnabled = false
    toggleButton = sender
    activeNode?.runAction(rotate,completionHandler: enableButtonnn)
}
func enableButtonnn (){
    toggleButton?.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this would be to save the original coordinates of the object in the scene, as soon as it is loaded. Then, use the [rotateTo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction/1524044-rotateto) method (instead of rotateBy) to achieve the desired rotation.

Example:

```
let originalPosition = activeNode?.position

let rotate = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: originalPosition.x, y: (originalPosition.y - .pi/2), z: originalPosition.z, duration: 0.5)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on line "let zPosition = activeNode?.zPosition" as follows:    Value of type 'SCNNode' has no member 'zPosition'; did you mean 'position'?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, and let me know if you are still having any issues.